# I'm confused with the this keyword in javascript, I want to know if I can do what I intended?

Tags: javascript, function, this

This code works fine, although what I'm interested in knowing is, if there's a way that works better and is which I prefer better, which it seem to not be working. Is it possible to do it that way, check the second code example in order to comprehend, what I have in mind when I say "preferred way".

**code 1**

```
function a(y){this.b=y;};
var ax = new a("oka");
alert(ax.b);
```

**code 2** (preferred way but does not work)

```
function a(){this.b = alert(y);this.y = y;}
var ax = new a();
ax.y="okay";
ax.b;
```

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're looking for with your second example -- could you explain it in a more abstract way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `this` is mostly fine, but the problem is that this line:

```
this.b = alert(y);
```

...**calls** `alert` and assigns its return value to `b`. If you wanted `b` to be a function, you'd do:

```
this.b = function() {
    alert(this.y);        // Note `this`
};
```

...so:

```
function a() {
    this.b = function() {
        alert(this.y);
    };
}
var ax = new a();
ax.y = "okay";
ax.b();                   // Note the ()
```

---

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is to give constructor functions (functions you call via `new`) names starting with a capital letter. So `A` rather than `a`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a function to the `this.b` property, you can do it like so:

```js
// Declare the a variable.
var a = {};
// Set the a.b property.
a.b = function(){alert('hi');}
// Call the function set on a.b.
a.b();
```